# How to find the next auto increment value in MySQL with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, auto-increment

I'm working on a web application that has been written with PHP and MySQL. I've used PDO in it.
I need to know **how can I find the next auto increment value in MySQL with PDO** ?
Because I want to name something (For example: image path) with records ID numbers. If I delete items from table, my application must assing the next auto-increment value to the new item.

Does `$db->lastInsertId()` do it ?

Comment: You asked: "Does $db->lastInsertId() do it?"  Well, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you **can't** get *last inserted id* before insert.

So, do it usual way:
Insert data into table **first**, then get inserted id, and then rename something